# I created a for loop and it doesnt work, but the while loop does, any sugestions?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Why doesnt this for loop work while the while loop does

```
for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}

int j = 1;

while(j != 11) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(j);
   j++;
}
```

Comment: `doesn't work` as in?

Comment: You want `i < 10`, NOT `i > 10`

Comment: i recommend [reading the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) for comparison. and seeing that you're simply using it the wrong way around. it must be `i <10`

Comment: FYI - for such "basic" code you could use code snippets - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019 - eg. type for and hit tab and the for loop should be generated

Comment: The middle part of a `for` is the condition that MUST BE TRUE for the loop iteration to proceed. Ask yourself, at the beginning of the loop after assigning 0 to `i`, is the condition true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to mix up comparers. A good way to remember for me is the heart. <3 because I know that's read as "Less than three".

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to get confused when starting out, you just mixed up the condition.

As of why your `for` does not work is because it starts with `i = 0` then checks if if 0 is greater than 10 which is not that's why it will not excute the loop body and terminates the loop.

In your `while` loop, initially `j = 1` then while checks if 1 is not equal to 11, which is true so loop body will execute until j is not equal to 11.